# xml layout: distance between the components not even

Tags: android, xml-layout

I am trying to place my TextView items with the same distance between each others but the distance is not even. I used  "android:layout_marginTop" to manage it but without success.

I appreciate any help.

[image]

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bustracker.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Latitude:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textLat"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textLat"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Longitude:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textLong"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textLong"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Bus available wifi:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textWifi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textLong"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textWifi"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textWifi"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="Time stamp:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You're adding more and more margin to each successive element.  So of course they're getting farther apart.  What else did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beacuse you're using `RelativeLayout` and you just dragged and dropped all `TextViews` thats why they are getting different margins. Now try this.

```
 <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.bustracker.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Latitude:" 
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Longitude:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLong"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Bus available wifi:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textWifi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Time stamp:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```